# Не запускается AGI скрипт

Tags: php, asterisk

В extensions.conf

```
exten => _XXXX,1,AGI(get_phones.php) 
exten => _XXXX,2,Noop(${sss})
```

В get_phones.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
require('phpagi.php');

$agi = new AGI();

$agi->set_variable('sss', 'test');
```

В консоли:
[image: вывод в консоли]

Comment: Ну и бог с ним. Вопрос-то какой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в символе переноса строки. Скрипт создавался в Windows, и по-умолчанию использовал последовательность EOL (CRLF). После того, как я поменял на LF, все заработало.